# How to use C# 9 in Blazor WebAssembly project?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-5

I've created a new Blazor WebAssembly project in Visual Studio which, by default, targets .NET Standard 2.1 and therefore uses C# 8.

I've also written a library written for .NET 5 and used C# 9 in it.

How can I use this library in my Blazor project? I can't reference a .NET 5 library in a .NET Standard 2.1 project.

- When I change the target framework of the library to .NET Standard 2.1 I cannot use C# 9 anymore in the library project. When I explicitly set the LangVersion in the csproj to 9.0 all of my record types get compile errors that some predefined type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit is not defined
- When I change the target framework of the Blazor project to .NET 5 and reference a .NET 5 library it doesn't work anymore (start up fails with HTTP Error 500.33 - ANCM Request Handler Load Failure)

Comment: Did you try to change the language version in `LangVersion` of the csproj?. See [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version). C# version and framework are not tighted so much.

Comment: FWIW I think it's too early in C# 9's tenure to be writing libraries in it.  Unless it's backward compatible with .NET Standard 2.1, you're really going to be limiting your audience.

Comment: If you multi target `.net 5` and `.NET Standard 2.1` you can use C# 9

Comment: Here is the relevant link on MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#when-to-target-net50-vs-netstandard

Comment: Blazor should work out of the box with .NET 5. This is what you get when you create a default Blazor App project with VS 16.8. I suspect there is an issue with your project setup in that regard.

Comment: I'm using 16.8.1 but it looks like the template isn't up to date. The link of Juxant helped me to migrate the project to .NET 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to migrate your Blazor WebAssembly project to .NET 5, check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-blazor-webassembly-projects